# Problemas con JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validate

Mi app funcionaba correctamente, ahora no me arroja ningún tipo de error,mientras tanto cuando ejecuto el depurador de mi navegador en envia al cogido de jquery.

```
 <!doctype html>
      <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.rut.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/validacion.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <?php include_once "lib/metodosbd.php";
          include_once "lib/metodos.php";?>
    </head>
    <?php valida_sesion(); ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">

//select dependiente
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#region").change(function () {
                        $("#region option:selected").each(function () {
                            id_region = $(this).val();
                            $.post("lib/getComuna.php", { id_region: id_region }, function(data){
                                $("#comuna").html(data);

                            });            
                    });
        });
    });                               
    $(document).ready(function(e) { 
        //valida rut de ingreso
    $("input#rut").rut().on('rutInvalido', function(e) {
           $("#mrut").fadeIn();

    });
      $("input#rut").rut().on('rutValido', function(e, rut, dv) {
        $("#mrut").fadeOut();
    });

     //valida rut buscador

    $("form#buscador input")
      .rut({formatOn: 'keyup', validateOn: 'keyup'})
      .on('rutInvalido', function(){ 
        $("#mrutb").fadeIn();
      })
      .on('rutValido', function(){ 
        $("#mrutb").fadeOut();

      });
      //copia rut en casilla sin digito verificador 
    $("#rutb").change(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            $("#rutsf").val(value);
        });
    //rut sin digito verificador
    $("input#rut").rut()
      .on('rutValido', function(e, rut){
        $('#rutsf').val(rut)
      });
      $("#rutb").change(function () {

          $("#rutb").each(function () {
                 $.ajax({
                     type:"GET",
                     url:"busca-cliente.php",
                     data:{busca: $("#rutb").val()},
                     dataType:"json",
                 }).done(function(res){

                        $('#nombre').val(res.nom);
                        $('#rut').val(res.rut);
                        $('#telefono').val(res.tel);
                        $('#direccion').val(res.dir);
                        $('#email').val(res.email);
                        $("#region").val([res.idre,res.desre]);
                        $("#comuna").val([res.idco,res.desco]);
                        document.getElementById("rut").focus();
                        if(res.mensaje == 1){
                            //no existe el cliente
                            $("#mensaje").text("El cliente no existe en la base de datos.");
                            $("#mensaje").css("display", "inline");
                            $("#btn-insert").css("display", "inline");
                            $("#btn-updete").css("display", "none");
                        }else{
                            //el cliente existe, puede actualizar
                            $("#mensaje").css("display", "none");
                            $("#btn-insert").css("display", "none");
                            $("#btn-updete").css("display", "inline");
                        }
                    });
          });
      })




    });

    </script>
    <body>
    <header>
    <div class="div-header">
      <section class="main row">
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1"> <img src="img/OXblanco.png" width="320" height="107" ></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 nom-usuario"><?php echo $_SESSION['nombre_per']; ?></div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <h2 style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:20px;">Ingresar Clientes</h2>

      <section class="main row" >
        <div class=" col-lg-12">

           <form  method="get" id="buscador" class="form-horizontal style-form">
           <span style="margin-left:18px; margin-top:15px;" class="help-block">Utilice esta casilla para buscar al cliente, si el cliente existe los campos se completarán automáticamente, de lo contrario es necesario ingresarlo.</span>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-sm-4" for="rutb" style="margin-top:1%;">Buscar cliente</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">

              <input name="rutb"  style="margin-top:5px;" type="text"  id="rutb"  class="form-control" />

              </div>
            </div>
           <span id="mensaje" class="alert-advertencia" ></span>
           <div class="alert-rutb" id="mrutb">El rut no es valido</div>
         </form>

        </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <form method="post" id="ingresar" class="form-horizontal style-form" onSubmit="return Comprobar();">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                  <label class="col-sm-3  control-label" for="rut">Rut :</label>
                                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                                      <input id="rut" name="rut" type="text" class="form-control">
                                        <div class="errores-iz" id="mrut">El rut no es valido</div>
                                  </div>
                                  <label for="nombre" class="col-sm-3  control-label">Nombre :</label>
                                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                                      <input id="nombre" name="nombre" type="text" class="form-control">
                                     <div id="mnom" class="errores-de">El nombre no es valido</div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="region">Región :</label>
                                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                                      <select class="form-control" id="region"  name="region">
                                        <option  value="0">Seleccione</option>
                                        <?php get_region();?>
                                      </select>
                                       <div class="errores-de" id="mregion">Seleccione una region.</div>
                                  </div>
                                 <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="comuna">Comuna :</label>
                                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                                      <select class="form-control" name="comuna" id="comuna" >
                                      <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
                                      <?php get_comuna();?>
                                      </select>
                                      <div class="errores-de" id="mcomuna">Seleccione una comuna.</div>
                                  </div>
                               </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="telefono" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Teléfono :</label>
                                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                                      <input id="telefono" name="telefono" type="text" class="form-control">
                                    <div class="errores-iz" id="mtel">El teléfono no es valido </div>
                                    <div class="errores-iz" id="mtel2">El número de telefono debe tener 9 digitos </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <label for="direccion" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Dirección :</label>
                                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                                      <input id="direccion" required name="direccion" type="text" class="form-control">
                                  </div>
                            </div>
                             <div class="form-group">
                                 <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                                  <label for="email"   class="col-sm-4 control-label">Email :</label>
                                  <div class="errores-iz" id="memail">Debe ingresar el email</div>
                                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                                      <input id="email" name="email" type="email"  required class="form-control">
                                  </div>
                                 <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                                <input name="rutsf" type="hidden"  id="rutsf" />
                             </div>

                            <div class="form-group">

                             <button type="submit" name="insertar"  class="button" id="btn-insert">Insertar</button>
                             <button type="submit" name="actualiza"  style="display:none;" class="button" id="btn-updete">Actualizar</button>
                            </div>

                            </form>
                </div>



    </div>
```

La app Envia el rut a la pagina busca-cliente.php y este devuelve un array de typo json, pero tengo la sospecha de que es el dato el que no se enviá.Ejecute busca-cliente.php y retorna los datos.

```
<?php
include_once "lib/conexion.php";
$rutbuscador=$_GET['busca'];
  if(!empty($rutbuscador)){
    $con=conectar();

     $sqls = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE     (RutAux = '$rutbuscador')"; 

$query= sqlsrv_query($con,$sqls);

if(sqlsrv_has_rows($query)){
        for($f = 1; $f <=1 ;$f++){
            $fila=sqlsrv_fetch_array($query,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

            $NOM=$fila['NomAux'];
            $RUT=$fila['RutAux'];
            $DIR=$fila['DirAux'];
            $FON=$fila['FonAux1'];
            $EM=$fila['EMail'];
            $REGID=$fila['Region'];$REGDES=$fila['Descripcion'];

            $COMDES=$fila['ComDes'];$COMID=$fila['ComAux'];
            $clientes= array("rut" =>$RUT, "nom" => $NOM,"tel" => $FON,"dir" => $DIR,
                             "email" => $EM,"idre" => $REGID,"desre" => $REGDES,
                             "idco" => $COMID,"desco" => $COMDES,"mensaje"=> 0);

            }
        echo json_encode($clientes);

    }else{
        $clientes= array("rut" =>$rutbuscador,"nom" => "","tel" => "","dir" => "","email" => "","mensaje"=> 1,"idre" => 0,"idco" => 0);
        echo json_encode($clientes);
    }
}
```

?>

PD: La validacion del rut y el select anidado funcionan correctamente.

Comment: y la pregunta es ??? el error que te marca es???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- Como primera como sugerencia, creo que deberías poner tu codigo Javascript al final del body, de esta forma termina de cargarse la pagina y sus elementos...

A veces falla cuando lo pones arriba.

2- Revisa que tu json no ande recibiendo acentos, apóstrofes,etc. para asegurar codifica los campos no numericos con utf8_encode o haciendo *echo json_encode($clientes, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)*;

3- Para verificar que se ejecute la petición al busca-cliente.php, presiona F12 en chrome y ve a network elige sólo XHR, y mira que se liste este archivo, haces click sobre él y mirá en la pestaña **Headers->formData**. Ahí tienes todo el detalle de la petición.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias al punto 3 pude capturar un error el cual es: Warning: sqlsrv_has_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\clientesv2\busca-cliente.php on line 11

Revise la consulta y me di cuenta que la modificaron, con la consulta correcta, pero sigue sin volver a funcionar probé agregando un error a los atributos de ajax y me imprime el arlet , como puedo concadenar el error ?

```
 $.ajax({
             type:"GET",
             url:"busca-cliente.php",
             data:{busca: $("#rutb").val()},
             dataType:"json",
             error: function(){
             alert("error");
             }

         }).done(function(res){
                $('#nombre').val(res.nom);
                $('#rut').val(res.rut);
                $('#telefono').val(res.tel);
                $('#direccion').val(res.dir);
                $('#email').val(res.email);
                $("#region").val([res.idre,res.desre]);
                $("#comuna").val([res.idco,res.desco]);
                if(res.mensaje == 1){
                    //no existe el cliente
                    $("#mensaje").text("El cliente no existe en la base de datos.");
                    $("#mensaje").css("display", "inline");
                    $("#btn-insert").css("display", "inline");
                    $("#btn-updete").css("display", "none");
                }else{
                    //el cliente existe, puede actualizar
                    $("#mensaje").css("display", "none");
                    $("#btn-insert").css("display", "none");
                    $("#btn-updete").css("display", "inline");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax({
             type:"GET",
             url:"busca-cliente.php",
             data:{busca: $("#rutb").val()},
             dataType:"json",
             error: function(){
             **alert("error");** //Este alert te lo va imprimir siempre proque no está como un evento, sino como un atributo -> Investiga sobre el onError
             }

1- Puedes hacer traceo del proceso paso a paso desde la pestaña Source del Inspector, y ver que la cosa vaya como quieres.

2- En network fijate si en la llamada te devuelve el JSON que esperas o vuelve a dar un error. Puedes hacer un console.log(res); para ver si imprime el resultado del post en el Console del Inspector.

Comment: Por favor no publiques múltiples respuestas, revisa [answer] elimina una web las dos y edita la otra para agregar lo que falte

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCIONADO!!!! El error es sencillo la app dejo de funcionar cuando des-comente el print_r : conecto, bueno si comento esta linea la aplicacion funciona function conectar(){

```
        $server="localhots";
        $bd="clientes";
        $pass="";
        $coninfo= array("Database"=>$bd,"UID"=>"sa","PWD"=>$pass,"CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8");
        $con = sqlsrv_connect($server, $coninfo);

            if($con){
                //print_r("conectado a: ".$bd);
            }else{
                ?>
                <div class="alert-false" role="alert">Error: <?php die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));?></div> 
                <?php
            }
            return $con;
```

}